# Excel Situation where i need to add time in three column and then total time in 4th column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem in excel in the below example.

```
TimeA   TimeB   TimeC         Time(A+B+C) 
5h 20m  4h 10m  3h 40m 10s    13h 10m 10s
```

Can we set some formula to get that output?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula, which you may have to confirm with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:C2,"h",""),"m",""),"s","")," ",":")))
```

Apply the custom format `h"h" m"m" s"s"` to the output cell.

[image]

You can also substitute `SUMPRODUCT` for `SUM` and avoid having to confirm with CSE.